# Integer overflow (Smallest file size that will make the integer in program become negative in bits)

Tags: c

I have a written a digital sign calculator in C. I need to know is the smallest size of the file (in bytes) which causes the signature to be negative

The program reads in bytes from a file as char then store it in an integer and keeps adding use to the integer until EOF has reached. The program works fine.

```
FILE *fp;
char inpfile[20];
char c;
int sumdigsig = 0;

// reading in the name of the file using inpfile
printf("Please Enter name of the File:\n");
scanf("%s",inpfile);
// checking if the file exisits
if((fp = fopen(inpfile,"r")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"File does no Exsist\n");
        exit(1);
}
// If the file exsists using fgetc to read in until endoffile is reached
// and casting char to int and suming it 
  c = fgetc(fp);
while(c != EOF){
        sumdigsig += (int)c;
        c = fgetc(fp);
}
printf("%d\n",sumdigsig);

}
```

The program works fine, it is just a reference so that you know what is happening. running really large file results in a negative number as expected but I need to know what file size in bits will cause the integer to overflow and be negative.

Comment: If this is just a sum of bytes, then if they're all zeroes, never, or if they're 255, then within 2^23 of them.

Comment: Note that signed integer overflow has an undefined behavior, so you should not "expect" anything specific.

Comment: This sort of "digest" is really useless since it doesn't verify much of anything. Consider a simple CRC or, ideally, something more robust like SHA2-256. At least use an unsigned value when negative values aren't meaningful.

Comment: @tadman can you please elaborate why the number is 2^23. Thanks

Comment: Hint: What if `(int)c` is never non-zero? This will never overflow. What if all bytes are  >127? Then `c` is always negative so it could wrap positive. The smallest size is *one byte*. Read up on [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to avoid confusion here.

Comment: Given `char c`, the code `c = fgetc(fp);` is wrong.  `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  `EOF` doesn't fit into a `char` value.

Comment: If one wants to calculate a value, it should be a variable. However, @EugeneSh. makes a good point.

Answer (score 2):

**I need to know what file size in bits will cause the integer to overflow and be negative.**

(Do you mean "file size in **bytes**"?  Files are rarely measured in bits.)

The way you are doing it, this all depends upon the bytes in the file.  As soon as the sum of the bytes that you are adding together exceeds `INT_MAX` (see `limits.h`), the value of the `int` cumulative sum will wrap to a negative value.

Thus, the maximum number of bytes *for a particular file* would be one fewer than the number of bytes that caused the summation to exceed `INT_MAX`.  i.e., one less than the number of bytes you have read from the file at the point where the sum first exceeds `INT_MAX` -- or, in practical terms of detecting this in code, first becomes negative.

And, as one of the comments points out, if all the bytes are `0x00`, then even an infinitely large file will never meet this criteria.

**EDIT 1 :** With respect to the comment about overflow behavior being undefined, instead of detecting if the sum has become negative, test instead whether or not `(INT_MAX - sum)` is less than the most recently read byte's value, *before* adding that byte's value to the sum.

**EDIT 2 :** Expressed in code:

**the core loop as I would re-write it**

```
c = 0;
bytes = 0;
while (1) {
    if ((c = fgetc(fp)) == EOF) break;

    if ((INT_MAX - sumdigsig) >= c) {
        sumdigsig += c;
        bytes++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

**sample runs**

```
head -c 1073741824 < /dev/urandom > large-file-of-random-bytes

./sum-file-bytes
Please Enter name of the File : large-file-of-random-bytes
sum is : 2147483572; read 16845621 bytes to reach that sum

head -c 1073741824 < /dev/zero > large-file-of-zeros

./sum-file-bytes
Please Enter name of the File : large-file-of-zeros
sum is : 0; read 1073741824 bytes to reach that sum
```

Answer (score 0):

In both 64-bit & 32-bit machine, the signed-integer value range is `-2,147,483,648 to  2,147,483,647`

So if "`sumdigsig`" crosses the "(positive) maximum value" then it will go back to the negative range.

**Let us consider a small example:**
Consider if the range is -10 to +9

```
   --->   -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  ----
  |                                           |
   ---    +9 +8 +7 +6 +5 +4 +3 +2 +1  0   <---
```

consider a = 4.
So if you do a = a + 6 i.e then will become -10 because it exceeds the range.

In the same way for an integer, if the value crossed the maximum value, then it will go back to the negative range.

**Proof:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // a contains the maxium value
    int a = 2,147,483,647;
    a = a + 1; 
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
-2,147,483,648
```

**Suggestion:** Instead of using the `signed-integer` go with `unsigned Integer`. U can get a big range i.e `2,147,483,647 + 2,147,483,648`

Comment: "if "sumdigsig" crosses the "(positive) maximum value" then it will go back to the negative range." may be what you  have experienced, yet `int` overflow is not defined.  Other things may happen.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your Awnser with an example? I didn't understand what undefined means.

Comment: With `int a = 2,147,483,647;
    a = a + 1;`, C does not specify "go back to the negative range".  Instead it is _undefined behavior_ meaning anything can happen, such as code crash.

Comment: Is it a compiler dependent? Because I ran the above code in the latest version of GCC compiler. it worked fine.

Comment: Even if it runs as hoped today, it might not run so tomorrow.  C spec says "An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow".  See [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).